# How to set up an Async web server with ESP-IDF?

Tags: asynchronous, webserver, esp32, esp-idf

First message for me on stackovf ever :)
Hoping to find some indication/help here as I must admit, I’m completely stuck, and almost desperate.

Working on an ESP-IDF project using VScode and platformio, and I want to build an async web server using CSS bootstrap lib and JS scripts.

I tried to port (from Arduino to esp-idf) the ESPAsyncWebServer/AsyncTCP libraries, but it started to imply way too much of a hassle for me... I obviously am not skilled enough. I also looked for an equivalent, and to built-in functions. All I could find was out of my league to implement.
Has someone ever found a solution / a workaround / an esp-idf compatible library ?

I’ve spent two days on the subject, but ESP-IDF is way less documented/used (and PlatformIO version is even « worse » from this point of view).
I still can’t understand the gigantic knowledge gap between using ESP-IDF env VS Arduino env… With Arduino my webserver was set up and running in less than an hour. 
So I must ask this one too : How do companies use the ESP32 ? Are they building their software from scratch? Are they using the Arduino environnement ..? Am I missing something ??

Obviously, my last solution is to go back to Arduino, which would be for me, kind of an admission of failure of improvement…
So any hint, suggestion, or help, would be very very much appreciated, thanks in advance !!

Comment: Hi Nick_mgn, welcome to SO! It's unclear what exactly is your problem and how we can help - you've posted no code and have multiple questions in your post. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) The vanilla approach in ESP IDF is to use the [HTTP server](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/esp_http_server.html) which is has less features and is written in C. But requests are still asynchronously handled and you should be able to implement anything you need. Have a look at the sample application in the docs.

Comment: Arduino environment is great for prototyping and hobby use (because you get something up and running in 1 hour, as you've noticed). I don't know about other companies, but I won't consider Arduino for actual products due to quality and stability concerns. I write most of the app myself on top of ESP IDF, pulling in selected third party libraries (as few as humanly possible - the cloud connection, JSON parsing, other grunt work). Can't point you to a beginner-friendly, easy-to-use HTTP library on top of ESP IDF, sorry.

Comment: Hello Tarmo, thank you for your helpful messages. You are perfectly right, and maybe I misphrased my questions. For the lack of included code, it’s because I had none to show. But you perfectly answered to me, and I need to have a look at the http server lib and test further. The Arduino environnement needed the specific Async lib, and that confused me. Thank you for that information, I’ll get back to you if I get some results :)

Comment: About the Arduino env. I totally agree with you on the « prototyping only » use case, and I also build all the core lib I need on top of bare ESP-IDF. Having no experience or particular knowledge in wifi protocols make me having a bad time on this one, thought. Thank you for your tips and info :)